# Bluemix SQL Service - How to REORG Table

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-cloud, alter

I am using an SQL Service in Bluemix. All was fine till I had to alter a Table. After altering the table, I have to run the REORG command which I am not able to do. How to run the REORG command for an SQL service in Bluemix. My assumption is that it can be only done by an admin in Bluemix. If so then it is a major drawback since I cant see any support forum for Bluemix. Any guidance will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: When you say you are "not able to do" the reorg, what do you mean exactly? Do  you not know how? Do you get an error? Something else?

Answer (score 2):

run the reorg from the console using the admin stored procedure:

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD ('REORG TABLE ')
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're referring to a SQL Database service instance on Bluemix. I suggest you to open a support request using one of the following methods:

- Use the Support Widget. It is available from the user avatar in the 
     upper right corner of the main Bluemix UI.  After opening the support 
     widget panel, select Get Help > Get In Touch , select the type of assistance you need, and then fill out the support form.
- Use the Support Site 'Get Help' form. This form is available on a separate site that is made available for ticket submission when you cannot log into Bluemix and access the Support Widget. Go to http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport and fill in the support request form.

Comment: Thank you. I used the second option and have bookmarked it too. Hopefull I will get the needed support from Bluemix team. Thanks again